# Share an emacs session and each progammer uses their own key bindings

Tags: emacs

When pairing/swarming and working remotely we'd like to be able to share one user's Emacs instance and contribute equally to the "driving".

[tmate](https://tmate.io/) allows us to share and follow terminal session emacs which is nice because there's next to no lag and we can still see each other to talk over our video conf tool. However, some colleagues are usually using the non-terminal Emacs and struggle, and it's also frustrating for people not to be able to use their usual key bindings.

Does anyone know of a nice solution where remote team members can view the same Emacs instance on one colleague's machine and contribute using their personal key bindings and/or usual local Emacs instance?

Comment: Consider posting this question on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/